# Is $\mu_p$ the only nontrivial Galois module of size $p$?

Tags: galois-theory, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

Assume $p$ is prime. By $\mu_p$ I mean of course the $p$-th roots of unity.

More specifically I'm working in the context of the $p$ torsion of elliptic curves.

I guess having prime order narrows it down a lot with respect to what these modules can be, but I can't think of a proof for this statement.

Comment: Think about quadratic twists!

Comment: @Mathmo123 I'm not sure how quadratic twists change the structure of these modules, could you give a hint?

Comment: Suppose that $E[p]$ (with $p>2$) has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ as a Galois module. Try to think about the structure of $E_d[p]$: it has a submodule that becomes isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$. But this submodule is not trivial or $\mu_p$ in general: $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ acts on it via the character $\chi\colon G_{\mathbb Q}\to \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb Q)\to\{\pm1\}\subset(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is far from true. You are asking: how many maps are there from the absolute Galois group of (whatever your field is) to $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.

There are a lot (unless your field is algebraically closed or something). If nothing else, you have $\mu_p^{\otimes n}$ for any $n$.

Comment: Could you explain further how to construct such a module given a map from the Galois group to $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ ?

Comment: @Carmilo_Gallardo, sure! Given $\phi: G \to \mathbb{F}_p^\times$, let $M$ be the module whose underlying abelian group is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}p$ and let $\sigma \in G$ act by $\sigma \cdot m = \phi(\sigma)m$. More generally, giving a $G$-module structure on an abelian group $A$ is the same as giving a map from $G$ to the group of automorphisms of $A$.